# json_serializable not generating code for final fields and getters

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serializable

This is my class:

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class Foo {
  final int a = 0;
  int get b => 42;
}
```

The generated code doesn't include any of the `a` or `b` field:

```
Foo _$FooFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Foo();

Map<String, dynamic> _$FooToJson(Foo instance) => <String, dynamic>{};
```

**Note:** Please don't write solutions for doing something like `Foo(this.a)` or `Foo() : a = 0` etc. I need to keep my structure as it is.

Comment: Can you provide the full code, not part?

Comment: You have to write a constructor like Foo({required this.a}) otherwise it does not make sense to create a final int a and assign it to 0. This value, being final, will always be 0. If you put Foo({required this.a}) the generated code will include a. And you will be able to initialize it when instanciating Foo.

Comment: @ManuH68 For simplicity, I used `final int a` but the use case is definitely not this. What if I have `final now = DateTime.now()`, will it make sense? Also, you didn't mention anything about the getter.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer - this won't be possible as this is done intentionally by design.

---

If adjusting your model structure is out of the question, you can try manual conversion or a mix of these two.

After encountering the same issues myself, not long ago, I opted in for [manual converting my models](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json) - and also a combination of two in some cases.

With `@JsonSerializable`, you can make use of the from/to generated methods, and then in addition, manually convert your final and getter fields.

Another option you can try, at least for the getter fields, is making use of `@JsonSerializable(createFactory: false)`. This will indicate the engine to convert getters as well.

I suggest reading [Flutter JSON Docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json) in detail and figuring out what will suit you the most, depending on your models, what you want, or what you can compromise on.

Worth reading the [Github thread on getter conversion](https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/496).

There's no out of the box workaround for final fields though, but as per this [Github thread on final fields](https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/891), PRs are welcome :)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. But I can't use the manual approach because I'm also using `cloud_firestore_odm` generator. Could you please share the code for mixing two approaches? I'm not aware of it besides the `toJson`/`fromJson` callbacks but they too don't work in these situations. Setting `createFactory: false` solves my issue of including both `a` and `b` in the generated `toJson()` but with this the `fromJson()` method doesn't get generated. But you definitely deserve a +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want easier json parsing, use Dart Data Class Generator extension in VS Code.

Comment: Thanks but I am using Android Studio.

Comment: hmm. Please check this.
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12429-dart-data-class

Answer (score 0):

I think since `a` is final, it is considered a constant and not  variable and `b` is a getter and not a variable, there are no variables (fields) for `json_serializable` to generate code for.

You need to add a default constructor before `json_serializable` can run. Since you have no fields, you wil have an empty constructor and empty methods generated.

```
class Foo {
  final int a = 0;
  int get b => 42;

  const Foo();

  factory Foo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Foo();

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{};
}
```